# Django makemigrations doesn't work with UndefinedColumn error

Tags: django

This is what I got when I run makemigrations on python3.8 and django 3.2.12

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "type" does not exist
```

I even tried cleaning up my db but still got this error. I have no idea what column "type" refers to. The message doesn't even tell which table it is from. And doesn't makemigrations not do anything with the db?

I tried on my other projects and not facing this issue.

Know what is the cause?

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "type" does not exist
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 103, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 294, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    tables = self.connection.introspection.table_names(cursor)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 52, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 47, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_cockroachdb/introspection.py", line 13, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("SELECT table_name, type FROM [SHOW TABLES]")
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/yxzeng/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "type" does not exist
```

This even happens to my new built cockroachdb

Comment: please share the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Seems like `django_cockroachdb` expects a certain table to have `type` as a column. Have you tried running `migrate` first before making new migrations?

Comment: @BrianDestura yes, I even tried to recreate the cockroachdb and migrate full the start, but still have this error